# How to prevent inserting rows with no two rows will have same (duplicates) value

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nhibernate, concurrency, locking

When multiple users are accessing the application,the application should not allow to insert duplicate columns(Eg: Name column in users table where name is unique).

How I am doing this is, in the button click event I am checking whether the name exists in db. this shows validation error if it is exists(duplicate);This works perfectly when single user accessing the app.

But, when 2 users concurrently inserting a row(user) with same column name it is allowing to inserting records with same name, because by the time  first user's request hit the db for checking whether the name already exists, second user's record(with duplicate name) is not yet inserted.

so, no validation is showing.

How to fix this issue in nhibernate sessions?.Can I use locking?
please advice.

Answer (score 1):

You should enforce this with a unique constraint on the database. Then when committing your insert transaction you should catch the error of the constraint violation. That's one of the things a database is great at doing.